# DB Architecture to store list of images

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have a model `PhotoAlbum`:

```
class PhotoAlbum(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, auto_created=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

And i need to store a list of photos, and when i send a GET request i should see the photos in the format like:

> GET /albums

```
{
   'id': 'randomUUID',
   'name' : 'MyAlbum'
   'photos': [
        {
            "id": "randomUUID",
            "image": "photo.jpg",
        },
        {
            "id": "randomUUID",
            "name": "photo2.jpg",
        }
    ]
}
```

So, to realize this i want to create 2 more models:

```
class Image(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, auto_created=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='media/')

class AlbumImage(models.Model):
    album = models.ForeignKey(PhotoAlbum, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = Image()
```

And create two serializers: for `PhotoAlbum`, and for `Image` (to show url).

Is it good solution to solve this task? Can you offer the more optimal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A slightly better solution may be to use a serializer that can handle both models, so you don't need to create two separate serializers. You can use a `ModelSerializer` so:

```py
class ImageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = AlbumImage
        fields = ['id', 'image']

class PhotoAlbumSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    photos = ImageSerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = PhotoAlbum
        fields = ['id', 'name', 'photos']
```

Now, you need to use `PhotoAlbumSerializer` to serialize the data and then return the response.

Answer (score 0):

Is the ID relevant for the user? Most likely not. In that case, you can just send an array of URLs. You'd use a [StringRelatedField](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#stringrelatedfield) or a [MethodField](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield) in your serializer.

You should also leverage a [ManyToManyField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField), since your AlbumImage model is simply an association table. If you don't care for properties of the association, such as ordering, a title or a description, you don't even have to declare a model (Django creates a table for you behind the scenes).

Make sure to [prefetch_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) on your queryset, to avoid major performance issues.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but the json format in the question is the required output, you can't change it

Comment: Then what do you mean by "Is it good solution to solve this task? Can you offer the more optimal?"? It seems that's only solution if you can't change the format of the output. Anyways, the other I suggested still apply.